# Configure ASP.NET Session State at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

We have an ASP.NET web site that uses SQL Server session state.  The state is configured in `Web.config` like:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="data source=TheServer;
    User ID=TheUser;password=ThePassword;" cookieless="false" timeout="480"/>
```

But there are three environments (development / staging / production).  All the other connection strings are configured like:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Development_Db1" connectionString="..."/>
        <add name="Production_Db1" connectionString="..."/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

At runtime, we pick one to connect to the database based on hostname.  Unfortunately, the Session State connection string appears to be hard coded in `web.config`.

Is there a way to configure SQL Server session state at runtime, or make it refer to a connection string from the `connectionStrings` section?

Comment: So basically you have information of all environments in one config file? Do you not want to use one file per environment?

Comment: @GôTô: Yes, all information for all environments is in one config file.  Working on a relatively old system here, my job is to swap it from in-process to sqlserver state.

Comment: This is a good question in general, but I don't like the idea of keeping all the connection strings in one place. Too much chance that production writes to development environment or vice versa...

Comment: @RedFilter I agree completely. I've worked in scenarios before trying to reference production and development environments from the same place, and it's easy to mess things up.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As it turned out, there was a fairly easy way of doing this.  Session State provides a feature called [Partitioning](https://web.archive.org/web/20130111000949/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163730.aspx), where you can spread your state over multiple SQL Servers.  You can provide a function to select the SQL Server based on the session id (SID).  The trick is that you can use this feature with ONE server, just to choose the server dynamically.

The `web.config` configuration looks like:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" 
              partitionResolverType="YourNamespace.PartitionResolver" 
              cookieless="false" 
              timeout="60" />
```

The function that chooses the SQL Server looks like:

```
public class PartitionResolver : IPartitionResolver
{
    public void Initialize() {}

    // The key is a SID (session identifier)
    public String ResolvePartition(Object key)
    {
        return <grab your config here>;
    }
}
```

This approach allowed us to continue using one web.config for both production and development.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above, I think you should not have both dev and prod connections strings in the web.config. You can use a Web Deployment Project so solve that issue. You can use a web deployment project to replace your config settings based upon the build. For instance, you could have an two external config files called connectionStrings.dev.config and connectionStrings.prod.config. If you build in Debug, it would use the dev.config, but if you build in Release, it would use prod.config.

It's a little different from VS 08 and 10. Here are some references:

VS 2008 - http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2010/01/07/deploy-aspnet-web-applications-with-web-deployment-projects/

VS 2010 - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx

Answer (score 1):

According to this article, you can customize the session state provider:

http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/asp.net-2.0/asp.net-2.0-customizing-the-session-state-mechanism.html

The information here could be used to design an environment-aware session state provider that could select the connection string based on a configuration in the .config file, or some other environmental key.

Comment: I'd have to reimplement the SQL Session State provider?  Ouch

Comment: You wouldn't want to totally re-implement it.  You would want to try to layer a custom SQL connection-string discovery mechanism over the existing SQL Session Provider.

Comment: But the existing SQL Session Provider uses the connection string from the `Web.config`.  So how could I reuse that?