# How to remove sessionState sqlConnectionString duplication

Tags: asp.net

I have a set of connection strings in the standard connectionStrings element of web.config

The sessionState element in web.config dictates the use of a sqlConnectionString attribute when using sql session state.

This typically results is a connection string being duplicated in 2 places in the file, and can result in them getting out of sync if someone forgets to change both locations.

What mechanism can I use to remove this duplication?

Example config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="IWouldLikeToUseThisConnectionStringForSessionState" value="..."
</connectionStrings>

<sessionState 
    mode="SQLServer" 
    allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"
    sqlConnectionString="DuplicatedConnectionStringHereAndCanGetOutOfSync"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of handling this may be to use [Partioning](https://web.archive.org/web/20130111000949/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163730.aspx), as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4771633/44869).